# Bootstrap: eCommerce responsive - correct HTML design pattern

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce, responsive-design

what I would like to do is a responsive list of products with twitter's boostrap...

let say I have a list of 20 products.

I would like that they would span trough site's width (by default 940 and won't be wider)... 
so in this (default) case I'd like to display 4 products in a row...I know this could be done like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3 product">.....</div>
    <div class="span3 product">.....</div>
    <div class="span3 product">.....</div>
    <div class="span3 product">.....</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span3 product">.....</div>
    <div class="span3 product">.....</div>
    <div class="span3 product">.....</div>
    <div class="span3 product">.....</div>
</div>

...
```

Everything is OK. But what I'd like to do is that this products would shrink if somebody is shrinking the page.... and it works too...

so far so good

now I'd like that when the width of the site is lower than 640.. I would display only 3 products per row...and if <480 than only 1 product per row...

So this is where things get messy... and since there are 4 products per row ion the HTML markup I would have to rearrange the DOM with JS, right? So it would look like ....

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="span4 product">.....</div>
     <div class="span4 product">.....</div>
     <div class="span4 product">.....</div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
     <div class="span4 product">.....</div>
     <div class="span4 product">.....</div>
     <div class="span4 product">.....</div>
 </div>

 ...
```

is there a better way?

Can you point me to a good article that discuass and explains this topic well?

---

edit:

one other thing.... bootstrap does left and right margins between spans in a row automatically for me. How can I achieve to apply the same margins between rows?

Comment: You probably want to be using row-fluid instead of just row. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: sure, I know... thanks... but still doesn't address my problem

Comment: You could do this by not using Bootstrap's spans. Just have one span12 which contains all of your items floating left. Set them to have 25% width at this level. Then using the media queries set them to have 33% width at max-width 640 and 100% width at max-width 480. Should work fine.

Comment: @BillyMoat: this would be an option if these floats wouldn't need a margin (right and bottom)... if I could use box-sizing: border... it wouldn't matter, but box-sizing is not supported on ie7 and 6... and sadly I need to support both :( ... but have found aworkaround for them..will do this way probably

Comment: @BillyMoat: please convert your comment to answer so I can award it... it works like a charm...thanx

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by not using Bootstrap's spans.

Just have one span12 which contains all of your items floating left.

Set them to have 25% width at this level.

Then using the media queries set them to have 33% width at max-width 640 and 100% width at max-width 480. Should work fine.